# Pixel-perfect projection matrix in OpenGL?

Tags: vb.net, opengl, projection-matrix

I'm using OpenTK and I would like to be able to render polygons and textures pixel perfect when their Z is a certain number, anywhere else in the projection doesn't matter (this is for a UI). Is there a way to set up a projection matrix that does this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opengl pixel perfect 2D drawing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040961/opengl-pixel-perfect-2d-drawing)

Comment: @NicolBolas I already tried that link and it didn't answer my question. I'm asking for a way to do it, not why it isn't working.

Answer (score 7):

First off, forget about that "special" Z value. When you want to draw a UI you switch to a orthographic projection, so that you can use Z for layering your graphics elements.

So the basic problem boils down to finding a orthographic projection that identity maps view space to viewport space. So let's see what OpenGL specifies about that:

> If a vertex in clip coordinates is given by
>
> ```
>  xc 
>  yc 
>  zc 
>  wc 
> ```
>
> then the vertex’s normalized device coordinates are
>
> ```
>  xd     xc/wc 
>  yd  =  yc/wc 
>  zd     zc/wc 
> ```
>
> #### 13.6.1 Controlling the Viewport
>
> The viewport transformation is determined by the selected viewport’s width
>   and height in pixels, *px* and *py*, respectively, and its center *(ox,oy)*
>   (also in pixels).
>
> The vertex’s window coordinates are given by
>
> ```
>  xw      px·xd/2  +   ox   
>  yw  =   py·yd/2  +   oy   
>  zw     (f−n)zd/2 + (n+f)/2 
> ```
>
> (…) separately for each primitive. The factor and offset applied to
>   zdfor each viewport encoded by n and f are set using **glDepthRange…**
>   (…)

So there you have it: To become pixel perfect you must find a projection that's exactly the inverse of the composition of vertex clip coordinates to vertex normalized coordinates to vertex window coordinates.

Let *w = 1* then you can substitute normalized for clip vertex coordinates and hence

```
  xw      px·xc/2  +   ox   
  yw  =   py·yc/2  +   oy   
  zw     (f−n)zc/2 + (n+f)/2 
```

Since we're not interested in the z coordinate we can rewrite this slightly

```
  xw     px·xc/2 + ox     px/2     0  ox   xc 
  yw  =  py·yc/2 + oy  =     0  py/2  oy   yc  
  ……           …             …     …   …   ……  
   1           1             0     0   1    1 
```

i.e. we have changed this into a homogenous matrix transformation

```
v_w = V · v_c
```

where v_c is the vertex position after projection from eye space to clip space and where V is the viewport transformation matrix

```
      px/2     0  ox 
 V =     0  py/2  oy 
         …     …   … 
         0     0   1 
```

So we can rewrite this again as

```
v_w = V · P · v_e
```

We're getting close. We want that

```
v_w = v_e
```

so `V·P` must be identity

```
I = V · P = V · V^-1
```

Hence we know that the projection matrix P must be the inverse of the viewport matrix

```
                  px/2     0  ox 
 P = inv V = inv     0  py/2  oy 
                     …     …   … 
                     0     0   1 

      2/px     0  -ox 
   =     0  2/py  -oy 
         …     …    … 
         0     0    1 
```

For the sake of non singularity we choose the Z row as (0,0,1,0) for vertex eye space Z in the range [0, 1]. So this is the projection matrix to use for pixel perfect mapping from eye space to `glViewport(ox, oy, px, py)`